# Applications and .bat script get locked in Windows 7 for some minutes

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, process

I am playing around with Windows batch scripts and simple C++ applications on a Windows7 64Bit PC.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot modify neither the batchfile nor the mingw-exe for minutes after I have launched them with a double-click using the Explorer. Suddenly after I time I can.

I stripped my batchfile down to one that only echoes a string to stdout and then exits. So there's no need to start some weired executable. Only the echo command.

As described above when the batchfile has finished I connot make changes on the file. It still seems to be locked for minutes.

Additionally, during this time I can see an entry in the Mircrosoft ProcessExplorer under the "System"-Process. As soon as the the entry disappears I can save the file again. It 
makes no difference if ProcessExplorer runs or not.

The same applies to the executable (not started from a batchfile).

This problem is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/296428/why-do-bat-scripts-get-locked-after-execution-in-windows-7), but the solutions proposed did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't save batch file shortly after running it on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/740621/cant-save-batch-file-shortly-after-running-it-on-windows-7)

Comment: While it is still simple messing around, as a workaround couldn't you always make a second one? Then you have a backup or the previous version to revert to also. I think I have had slowdowns like this before, I just leave the editing window up, and save to different files, then cleaup as nessiary when completed.  A whole minute of time , if it isn't something still running, could it be an active Virus scanner that keeps re-checking everytime that file or folder changes?

Comment: Starting the Application Experience service helped. So this thread is something like a duplicate of the one mentioned above. I appreciate your help.